# C# trying to cleanup code by using generic class

Tags: c#

at the moment everything I want working is good. But I am trying to clean it up a bit and was looking for some advice when using a generic class. I want to take void update, void add, and void delete and move it to another class then call it in my form when needed. My guess was to try using something like _delete then getters and setters but whenever i tried that i would get errors because I cant recognize listView1. Could someone point me in the right direction? My code is below.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace cartest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

            listView1.Columns.Add("Make", 60);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Model", 60);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Color", 50);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Miles", 50);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Condition", 90);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Interior", 60);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Highway MPG", 90);
            listView1.Columns.Add("City MPG", 90);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Price", 50);
        }

        private void add(string make, string model, string color, string miles, string condition, string interior, string highway, string city, string price)
        {
            string[] row = { make, model, color, miles, condition, interior, highway, city, price }; //adding rows to list
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void update()
        {
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxMake.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxModel.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxColor.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxMiles.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxCondition.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxInterior.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxHighway.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxCity.Text;
            listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text = textBoxPrice.Text;

            //After you update an item it clears the text
            textBoxMake.Text = ""; textBoxModel.Text = ""; textBoxColor.Text = ""; textBoxMiles.Text = ""; textBoxCondition.Text = ""; textBoxInterior.Text = ""; textBoxHighway.Text = ""; textBoxCity.Text = ""; textBoxPrice.Text = "";
        }

        //delete from list
        private void delete()
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);

                //After you delete it clears text
                textBoxMake.Text = ""; textBoxModel.Text = ""; textBoxColor.Text = ""; textBoxMiles.Text = ""; textBoxCondition.Text = ""; textBoxInterior.Text = ""; textBoxHighway.Text = ""; textBoxCity.Text = ""; textBoxPrice.Text = "";
            }
        }


        // add to list
        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add(textBoxMake.Text, textBoxModel.Text, textBoxColor.Text, textBoxMiles.Text, textBoxCondition.Text, textBoxInterior.Text, textBoxHighway.Text, textBoxCity.Text, textBoxPrice.Text);

            //After you add an item to list it clears text
            textBoxMake.Text = ""; textBoxModel.Text = ""; textBoxColor.Text = ""; textBoxMiles.Text = ""; textBoxCondition.Text = ""; textBoxInterior.Text = ""; textBoxHighway.Text = ""; textBoxCity.Text = ""; textBoxPrice.Text = "";
        }

        //update item in list
        private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            update();
        }

        //delete a item in list
        private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            delete();
        }

        //Click on an item, you get all the values in that row into the textbox
        //Used for update purposes
        private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxMake.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
            textBoxModel.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
            textBoxColor.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            textBoxMiles.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
            textBoxCondition.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
            textBoxInterior.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text;
            textBoxHighway.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[6].Text;
            textBoxCity.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text;
            textBoxPrice.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[8].Text;
        }

        private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string make = textBoxMake.Text;
            string model = textBoxModel.Text;
            string color = textBoxModel.Text;
            string miles = textBoxModel.Text;
            string condition = textBoxModel.Text;
            string interior = textBoxModel.Text;
            string highway = textBoxModel.Text;
            string city = textBoxCity.Text;
            string price = textBoxPrice.Text;

            openFileDialog1.FileName = "cars";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter ap = File.AppendText("cars.txt"))
                {
                    ap.WriteLine(make);
                    ap.WriteLine(model);
                    ap.WriteLine(color);
                    ap.WriteLine(miles);
                    ap.WriteLine(condition);
                    ap.WriteLine(interior);
                    ap.WriteLine(highway);
                    ap.WriteLine(city);
                    ap.WriteLine(price);

                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Prac\FinalProject\FinalProject\bin\Debug\cars.txt");

            for (int i = 0; i + 7 < fileLines.Length; i += 8)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(
                    new ListViewItem(new[]
                    {
                fileLines[i],
                fileLines[i + 1],
                fileLines[i + 2],
                fileLines[i + 3],
                fileLines[i + 4],
                fileLines[i + 5],
                fileLines[i + 6],
                fileLines[i + 7],
                fileLines[i + 8]
                    }));
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful of your usage of the word "generic". "Generic class" [means something very specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) in C#. It looks like what you're trying to do is just move some functionality out of the form into a separate class. The way to accomplish that might be to pass `listView1` into your new class' constructor, which would store it in a class member for add, delete, and move to reference when they're called.

Comment: Also; that's a pretty good sized chunk of code. Consider removing any logic that is not relevant to the task at hand so we have less to read. This question is also borderline off-topic; questions about *working* code are typically better received on CodeReview.SE

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Oh, sorry about that. Next time ill make sure I post to the right place

Comment: This looks like the goal is a class providing Data. Like something that will point at some from of DB at the end. For those it is rather important that you do not make a static class (a common mistake). Make a class that needs instantiation, then assign a instance to a static field. The fully static approach *will* come back to bite you. It does as surely as goto's and naked pointers. Functions like delete, add and update (wich should update one specific record) should have at least a bool return value to see if it worked.

Comment: (new comment due to limitations) A function like "query" or "retrieveList" should be used to return the list that you will then display. If you want to make any work more general, avoid ever accessing any GUI Element in the Data class, even via Parameters. It is another common mistake that will come back to bite you if you ever change the GUI

Comment: Thank you for all the advice guys. Also why did I get -2 rep? Should I have provided different information or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful of your usage of the word "generic". [Generic class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) means something very specific in C#. It looks like what you're actually trying to do is just move some functionality out of the form into a separate class. The way to accomplish that might be to pass `listView1` into your new class' constructor, which would store it in a class member for add, delete, and move to reference when they're called.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ListView listView;

    public MyClass(ListView lv)
    {
        listView = lv;
    }

    public void add(string make, string model, string color, string miles, string condition, string interior, string highway, string city, string price)
    {
        string[] row = { make, model, color, miles, condition, interior, highway, city, price }; //adding rows to list
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
        listView.Items.Add(item);
    }

    // Delete method goes here

    // Move method goes here
}
```

Then to use it, you could do something like:

```
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass foo = new MyClass(listView1);

        foo.add(textBoxMake.Text, textBoxModel.Text, textBoxColor.Text, textBoxMiles.Text, textBoxCondition.Text, textBoxInterior.Text, textBoxHighway.Text, textBoxCity.Text, textBoxPrice.Text);

        ...  // More code
    }
```